# Getting information about annotation in java via reflection

Tags: java, reflection, annotations

I have this annotation type class:

```
import java.lang.annotation.Retention;
import java.lang.annotation.RetentionPolicy;

@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface RemoteTcpAccess {

    public int port();
}
```

and apply it on another class like this:

```
@RemoteTcpAccess(port = 444)
public class CalculatorService {

    public int Add(int a, int b) {
        return a + b;
    }

    public void DisplayText(String text) {
        System.out.println(text);
    }
}
```

Now I get the CalculatorService Class object and try to get the information about RemoteTcpAccess annotation:

```
private static void CheckRemoteTcpAccess(List<Class> classes) {
        for (Class class1 : classes) {
            for (Annotation annotation : class1.getDeclaredAnnotations()) {
                if (AnnotationEquals(annotation, ComponentsProtocol.REMOTE_TCP_ACCESS)) {
             //GET INFORMATION
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private static boolean AnnotationEquals(Annotation classAnnotation, String protocolAnnotation) {
        return classAnnotation.toString()
                .substring(0, classAnnotation.toString().indexOf("("))
                .equals(protocolAnnotation);
    }
```

I am able to recognize if the class has applied RemoteTcpAccess annotation on it, but I cant get inforamtion about what fields has the annotation and what values have those fields, like :

Field port - value 444

Is there any way how to get those inforamtion via reflection?

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code should type check the annotation to see if is of type `RemoteTcpAccess`.  If so, cast the `Annotation` to the `RemoteTcpAccess` type.  From this type the `port` can be retrieved.

```
import java.lang.annotation.Annotation;

@RemoteTcpAccess(port = 322)
public class AnnotationTest {

    /**
     * @param args
     * @throws NoSuchFieldException
     * @throws SecurityException
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) throws SecurityException,
            NoSuchFieldException {
        Annotation anno = AnnotationTest.class
                .getAnnotation(RemoteTcpAccess.class);
        if (anno instanceof RemoteTcpAccess) {
            RemoteTcpAccess rta = (RemoteTcpAccess) anno;
            System.out.println(rta.port());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: very useful, I will check the instanceof keyword! but isnt anno always instanceof RemoteTcpAccess ?

Comment: @JohnSmith In this instance yes, but think about your situation (looping through annotations).  If there were multiple annotations on the class, they might not be of type `RemoteTcpAccess`.  If you perform the cast blindly and later the class gains an annotation, the code will break.

Answer (score 2):

You can call:

```
RemoteTcpAccess rta = clazz.getAnnotation(RemoteTcpAccess.class);
if(rta != null) //annotation present at class level
{
int port = rta.port();
}
```

In your case you can directly use specific annotation (`RemoteTcpAccess`) instead of  generic way of using `Annotation`. So this will trim down your loop to:

```
for (Class class1 : classes) {
    RemoteTcpAccess rta = class1.getAnnotation(RemoteTcpAccess.class);
    if(rta != null)  {
       int port = rta.port(); //GET INFORMATION
       ..
    }
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
 ((RemoteTcpAccess)annotation).port();
```

Answer (score 0):

From knowing about the ananlogy between interfaces and annotations, I'd say that this would work:

```
((RemoteTcpAccess) annotation).getPort()
```